# How would you say you "stopped wearing" something?

Tags: verbs, compound-verbs

How would you go about saying you "stopped wearing" something? I'm trying to say "I stopped wearing uniforms at X high school." and I'm incredibly tripped up by how to put verbs into this sentence.

I know how to say I was wearing something (「...きました。」) and that I wasn't wearing something (「...きませんでした。」), but I cant quite figure out how to say "stopped wearing".

Is 「Xこうこうでユニフォームをきるのをとまりました。」 correct?

Answer (score 3):

> Is 「Xこうこうでユニフォームをきるのを**とまりました**。」 correct?

No, it is not though it was a nice try.  Why not?

Mostly because you used 「とまる」, which is an intransitive verb.  You can never say 「～～**を**とまる」.  (You must say 「～～をと**め**る」 as 「とめる」 is transitive.)

In this context, however, 「やめる」 would be a far more natural verb choice than 「とめる」.  You can say:

> 「Xこうこう**では**ユニフォームをきるのを**やめました**。」

More naturally, we would use 「制服{せいふく}」 over 「ユニフォーム」, but that has nothing to do with grammar.

Advanced learners would need to know to say:

> 「X高校{こうこう}では制服を廃止{はいし}しました。」

Comment: "I stopped wearing uniforms at X high school."  と "They stopped wearing uniforms at X high school." とでは日本語訳が異なりませんか？

Comment: The latter is like saying "They got rid of uniforms at X high school." I believe やめる you can only use with single subjects "I, him", as well as  "we". It's not right to use it to describe a corporation's actions.

Comment: using 廃止 sounds wrong to me - doesn't that indicate that the school took a decision to get rid of uniforms (for everyone), ie to abolish the use of uniforms? Correct me if I'm wrong, but the OP seems to be saying that he/she took a personal decision to stop wearing a uniform.

Answer (score 3):

> I stopped wearing uniforms at X high school.

Although the above sentence given by the questioner should have only one meaning, since my understanding of English is insufficient, I understand it as the following two possible meanings.

Apart from the intention of the questioner, I'll try to present natural Japanese for each of these two interpretations.

#### Interpretation 1:

I am an authoritative person who can change the rules of this high school like the principal.
So, I decided to change school rules and abolish the students' uniforms or teachers' uniforms.
私｛わたし｝はＸ高校｛こうこう｝の（生徒｛せいと｝または教職員｛きょうしょくいん｝の）制服｛せいふく｝着用｛ちゃくよう｝を廃止｛はいし｝した。

#### Interpretation 2:

I am a student of X High School. In school rules, you are free to wear uniforms or wear plain clothes or casual clothes at school. I had been wearing uniforms until recently, but I decided to go to school with plain clothes.
私{わたし}はＸ高校｛こうこう｝に制服｛せいふく｝で行｛い｝くことをやめた。